# Where fingerprint sensor storages fingerprints. One finger not recognized anymore

Tags: 21.10, storage, fingerprint-reader, reinstall, dell-vostro

I have a fingerprint sensor in my machine (Dell Vostro 3515) and in the first instalation of 21.10 I registered one finger and it worked well, after reinstall 21.10 (I installed and removed Ubuntu 22.04 cause some things wasn't working) I can't use the same finger (indicator), cause it shows an error. When reinstalling I format \ to install the OS and keep \home but in \home i delete all "." folders. If someone knows something or knows any documentation that shows where the fingerprint is storaged I will be gratefull. I searched but could't find anything meaninfull.

Sorry about my english mistakes is not my main language.

Comment: What error exactly? (note: In Linux it's "/")

Comment: @ChanganAuto "Failled to enroll new fingerprint"